# What to translate Java Color to integer?

Tags: java, colors, opencl

I need to transmit an array of colors from Java to OpenCL and I just wondered to what type they are best translated. In some languages a Color is just a 32 bit integer, the Java docs sometimes hint it is as well but I never see this explicitly mentioned. As OpenCL only knows the basic types I wanted to translate the color array to an integer array, have it processed and next translate it back. Does it matter whether it is awt Color or javaFX color?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Color#getRGB()` ?

Comment: From an awt `Color` you can get an int representing the colour ([`getRGB()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB--)), or separate ints for [red](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed--), [green](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getGreen--), [blue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getBlue--) (and [alpha](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getAlpha--)) if that's what you need. What do you need?

Comment: I want a 4 byte integer where the bytes code respectively R G B A(lfa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the color is a 32 bit integer, it is important to know how that integer is encoded.

RGB(A) is an encoding into a 32 bit integer, the first 8 bits are the Red intensity, the next 8 bits are the Green intensity, the next 8 bits are the Blue intensity, and the last 8 bits (if used) is a transparency.

However, that 32 bit integer might encode a completely different color, like a CMYK color, or a color out of a different color system.

There's no magic to encoding color in a 32 bit integer, but there's no standard encoding which can encode every color, and there's no room in the 32 bit integer to specify which encoding was used.  So, no, there is no general solution.

Once you know the encoding that is required, or the encoding you will choose, that encoding will tell you if you can pack it into a 32 bit integer, and what the packing order and other details of setting the bits in that integer entail.

Comment: ***...first 8 bits are the Red intensity***  are this the MSB or LSB????

Comment: As I said before, it depends.  The colors were not designed to be transportable between architectures.  They were designed to match the hardware requirements of the machine.  So, if you are moving colors between architectures, you'll likely have to also handle reordering (provided you encoded them as 32 bit integers, and not as more-than-that bit color data structures). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space where RGBA maintains order, but many of it's cousins don't.

Comment: I am accustomed to Delphi colors and they are integers. I hoped for some overlooked function like `colorToInt32` in Java but you make it clear there is no such thing. Thanks for pointing that out to me and I'll code something myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own api that converts some known formats to your own, then use everywhere, whether it be opencl or cuda.

Then, you can add a function/method to it to separate color elements arrays such as array of reds, array of greens and array of blues and send it to gpu. You can directly use float4, int4, char4 but I'm not sure if you don't need mixed types. For example, 8bit integer red + 8bit integer green + 8bit integer blue + 32bit float transparency. These user-defined structs may have portability problems and be better when separated to primitive arrays.

```
HARDWARE/API ---> YOUR API ----> REDs ---> opencl buffer  >--┓
                       |                                     |
                       └-----> GREENs ---> opencl buffer  >--┨
                         |                                   |
                         └-----> BLUEs ---> opencl buffer >--┨
                                              |              |
                                              └--<-- GPU  <--┘
```

overhead of conversion to your api could be overcome by pipelining it, if this is something like a video feed.

When there is a streaming data of frames, a step could include concurrent substeps like:

- your api converts input to your format for frame X
- your format copies its colors to opencl buffers for frame X-1
- copy buffers to gpu for frame X-2
- compute on gpu for frame X-3
- copy results back to host for frame X-4
- convert result buffer to relevant hardware/api type color encoding for frame X-5

From a developer's view:

```
parallel_for
  processedImg[X]=myApi.getPixels(javaPicture[X]);
  processedImg[X-1].toOpenClBuffers();
  processedImg[X-2].compute();
  processedImg[X-3].toSourceFormat();
  ..
```

Comment: Thanks Huseyin, I'll try something based on int32 to begin with.